# How to append to an empty list in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to create an empty lsit and gardually fill that out with tuples. I've tried the following and each returns an error. My question is: how to append or add and element to an empty array?

My try:

```
A = []
A.append((2,5))   # return Error type Array has no field append
append(A, (2,5))  # ERROR: UndefVarError: append not defined

B =  Vector{Tuple{String, String}}
# same error occues
```

Comment: Try `append!(A, (2,5))`, `append not defined` means there is no function `append`.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/filling-an-array-of-structs-from-file-contents/78757).

Comment: @AndreWildberg That will not actually put a tuple inside `A`, but instead add two distinct elements, 2 and 5. This is how `append!` works. But the desired behavior is achieved with `push!`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not actually want to append, you want to *push* elements into your vector. To do that use the function `push!` (the trailing `!` indicates that the function modifies one of its input arguments. It's a naming convention only, the `!` doesn't do anything).

I would also recommend creating a typed vector instead of `A = []`, which is a `Vector{Any}` with poor performance.

```
julia> A = Tuple{Int, Int}[]
Tuple{Int64, Int64}[]

julia> push!(A, (2,3))
1-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2, 3)

julia> push!(A, (11,3))
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2, 3)
 (11, 3)
```

For the vector of string tuples, do this:

```
julia> B = Tuple{String, String}[]
Tuple{String, String}[]

julia> push!(B, ("hi", "bye"))
1-element Vector{Tuple{String, String}}:
 ("hi", "bye")
```

This line in your code is wrong, btw:

```
B = Vector{Tuple{String, String}}
```

It does not create a vector, but a *type variable*. To create an *instance* you can write e.g. one of these:

```
B = Tuple{String, String}[]
B = Vector{Tuple{String,String}}()  # <- parens necessary to construct an instance
```

It can also be convenient to use the `NTuple` notation:

```
julia> NTuple{2, String} === Tuple{String, String}
true

julia> NTuple{3, String} === Tuple{String, String, String}
true
```